# zenity yes/no dialogue instead of terminal prompt

Tags: gnupg, zenity

I am using zenity to make encrypting files easy for someone who dislikes using the terminal. So far so good. When user right clicks on file and selects encrypt option zenity presents user with list of keys on their keyring available for encrypting file with (gpg -k). But if owner trust or validity has not been set by the user for a particular key that is selected, then the user is prompted with a terminal window to confirm proceeding to encrypt with the selected key, or not. Is there a way to pop a zenity dialogue to present the user with such a confirmation request instead?

I realize yes/no dialogue boxes are available in zenity, but from what I have found so far it seems more applicable for instances in which a script requires a user to select yes or no in order to proceed with a script. But in this case, gpg initiates the prompt and only does so for some but not all keys selected.